# How many entries could the Craft database hold before it slows down?

Tags: entries, database, entry, performance

I'm pulling in some RSS feeds using Feed Me (https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) and turning those in entries automatically using a cron job.

You can imagine that producing a lot of entries over time ;) Is there a known limit for entries in the Craft database?

And is there perhaps a way to automatically delete entries after x amount of time?

Thanks, Bob

Comment: Not able to answer this myself but you might find this useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade

Comment: Also regarding automatic deletion. You could achieve that by writing a simple plugin that gets all entries over a certain age then delete them and calling that through CRON also.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a loaded question, but generally it's going to depend more on environmental limitations than anything with Craft itself.

If you're on a shared host along with 200 other accounts using the same MySQL server, then you'll likely notice slowdowns sooner than later.

If you're on a decent host with plenty of memory/disk/CPU available, then we've seen sites with 500k users/entries/assets/etc. running along just fine.

> And is there perhaps a way to automatically delete entries after x amount of time?

As Andrew pointed out in the comments, you could write a simple plugin that exposes a controller action that gets all entries over a certain age and deletes them.  Then you'd setup a CRON job to call that controller endpoint on whatever schedule you want.

Comment: Thanks Andrew en Brad, i'm going to check out the cron job for deleting entries, and perhaps cancelling stuck tasks as well. Would there be an example available somewhere? this would be my first plugin ;)

Comment: If it's your first plugin, this is a great place to get the starting framework: https://pluginfactory.io